# How do I fix arcolinux_repo is unknown in pacman

Tags: pacman, software-updates

I have a box with Arcloinux (D I think) and pacman has is not letting me update the system anymore, I get:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
[sudo] password for user: 
error: arcolinux_repo: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64? [Y/n] 
error: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" could not be looked up remotely
error: arcolinux_repo_3party: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64? [Y/n] 
error: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" could not be looked up remotely
error: arcolinux_repo_xlarge: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64? [Y/n] 
error: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" could not be looked up remotely
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 arcolinux_repo                                        92.1 KiB  52.3 KiB/s 00:02 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
 arcolinux_repo_3party                                165.9 KiB   470 KiB/s 00:00 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
 arcolinux_repo_xlarge                                 28.5 KiB   165 KiB/s 00:00 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
 core                                                 135.9 KiB   327 KiB/s 00:00 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
 extra                                               1572.6 KiB  3.63 MiB/s 00:00 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
 community                                              5.8 MiB  3.87 MiB/s 00:01 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
 multilib                                             149.4 KiB  1940 KiB/s 00:00 [-----------------------------------------------] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'arcolinux_repo.db' from bike.seedhost.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'arcolinux_repo_3party.db' from bike.seedhost.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'arcolinux_repo_xlarge.db' from bike.seedhost.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: too many errors from bike.seedhost.eu, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: arcolinux_repo: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64? [Y/n] 
error: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" could not be looked up remotely
error: arcolinux_repo_3party: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64? [Y/n] 
error: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" could not be looked up remotely
error: arcolinux_repo_xlarge: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64? [Y/n] 
error: key "93D1CCB2B2421F4B1CD0489774F5DE85A506BF64" could not be looked up remotely
error: failed to synchronize all databases (unexpected error)
```

How can I fix this?

I tried what Ibn Fulan suggested:

```
[user@OldNotebook ~]$ sudo pacman-keyring --init
sudo: pacman-keyring: command not found
[user@OldNotebook ~]$ sudo pacman-keyring --populate
sudo: pacman-keyring: command not found
[user@OldNotebook ~]$ sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (1)             Old Version  New Version  Net Change

core/archlinux-keyring  20210616-1   20210902-1     0.03 MiB

Total Installed Size:  1.35 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.03 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                        [---------------------------------------] 100%
downloading required keys...
:: Import PGP key 6D42BDD116E0068F, "Christian Hesse <arch@eworm.de>"? [Y/n] 
error: key "6D42BDD116E0068F" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
[user@OldNotebook ~]$ sudo pacman -U arcolinux-keyring-20230919-6-any.pkg.tar.zst
loading packages...
error: 'arcolinux-keyring-20230919-6-any.pkg.tar.zst': could not find or read package
```

After downloading the package from the link, I get the following:

```
sudo pacman -U arcolinux-keyring-20230919-6-any.pkg.tar.zst
[sudo] password for ron: 
loading packages...
warning: arcolinux-keyring-20230919-6 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (1)        Old Version  New Version  Net Change

arcolinux-keyring  20230919-6   20230919-6     0.00 MiB

Total Installed Size:  0.01 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                         [---------------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                       [---------------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                            [---------------------------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                      [---------------------------------------] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling arcolinux-keyring                                   [---------------------------------------] 100%
 >>> Run `pacman-key --init` to set up your pacman keyring.
 >>> Then run `pacman-key --populate arcolinux` to install the ArcoLinux keyring.
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
ron@OldNotebook ~/Downloads> sudo pacman-key --init
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: keyring_get_keyblock: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: keyring_get_keyblock failed: Invalid keyring
gpg: failed to rebuild keyring cache: Invalid keyring
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: keydb_search failed: Invalid packet
gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key 72964CF74904979E not found
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: keydb_search failed: Invalid packet
gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key 22031265073BFB70 not found
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: keyring_get_keyblock: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: Invalid keyring
gpg: validate_key_list failed
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpg: keyring_get_keyblock: read error: Invalid packet
gpg: keydb_get_keyblock failed: Invalid keyring
```

and there's more errors when I do `sudo pacman-key --populate` or `sudo pacman-key --populate arcolinux`

Comment: Sorry that I gave wrong command. Also I cannot understand why arcolinux github repo have the keyring package dating 2023 (probably because current keys may expire in 2023). About the last line `pacman -U`, have you downloaded the package from link?

Comment: I tried it and added the post abve. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you either don't have the signing keys or they are not populated in pacman.
Update the keyring

```
sudo pacman-key --init
sudo pacman-key --populate
```

If it doesn't work, download the latest [`arcolinux-keyring`](https://github.com/arcolinux/arcolinux_repo/raw/master/x86_64/arcolinux-keyring-20230919-6-any.pkg.tar.zst)
package and install it.

```
sudo pacman -U arcolinux-keyring-20230919-6-any.pkg.tar.zst
```

And repeat first two commands.

Edit:
I don't know why you tried to install `archlinux-keyring` (Arco and Arch are differet thing) but turns out that, too, is outdated. Install that manually, downloading [`archlinux-keyring`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/archlinux-keyring-20210902-1-any.pkg.tar.zst) and using

```
pacman -U archlinux-keyring-20210902-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
```

Also, assuming you are new to Linux, first you have to `cd` in the directory you downloaded the package, and the issue `pacman -U <package name>`   command